# Magento Custom Admin Module with a Image File

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to create an admin module in Magento.

Step 1: 
which contains the following fields

[image]

Step 2 : Filled some values and a Image

[image]

Step 3 : When i am trying to Save this Item, the item is saved Successfully but image is not showing here. But actually that images is copied in my Magento Media folder.

Step 4 : After the item saved successfully it is showing like this

[image]

But Actually i want it to show something like this

[image]

Here is My Code Please Find it.

**_prepareForm() - fieldset code :**

```
$fieldset->addField('image', 'file', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Image'),
    'name'      => 'image',
    'note' => '(*.jpg, *.png, *.gif)',
));
```

**_prepareForm()** :

```
<?php
class Namespace_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Measurement_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
  protected function _prepareForm()
  {
      $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                                      'id' => 'edit_form',
                                      'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                                      'method' => 'post',
                                      'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
                                   )
      );
      $form->setUseContainer(true);
      $this->setForm($form);
      return parent::_prepareForm();
  }
}
?>
```

**saveAction()** :

```
public function saveAction() {
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        $model = Mage::getModel('modulename/modulename');
        $model->setData($data)->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
        try {
            if ($model->getCreatedTime == NULL || $model->getUpdateTime() == NULL) {
                $model->setCreatedTime(now())
                    ->setUpdateTime(now());
            } else {
                $model->setUpdateTime(now());
            }
            $model->save();
            if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))) {
                try {
                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image');
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); // or pdf or anything
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                    // setAllowRenameFiles(true) -> move your file in a folder the magento way
                    // setAllowRenameFiles(true) -> move your file directly in the $path folder
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/modulename_images/' ;
                    $uploader->save($path, $model->getId().'.jpg');
                    $model->setImage($model->getId().'.jpg');
                    $model->save();
                }catch(Exception $e) {
                    print_r($e);
                    die;
                }
            }
            else {       
                if(isset($data['image']['delete']) && $data['image']['delete'] == 1)
                $data['image_main'] = '';
                else
                unset($data['image']);
            }

            // Mage::getModel('modulename/flatrates')->saveMultipleFlatrates($data, $model->getId(),$this->getRequest()->getParam('cat_id'));
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
                return;
            }
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }
    }
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Unable to find item to save'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

Anything wrong i did here ?

any ideas ?

If any spell mistakes i am really sorry.

Comment: could you please send me the code..? to moo.alyan@gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the image preview, you have to use the `image` field type, not `file`, like this (look at second parameter):

```
$fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Image'),
    'name'      => 'image',
    'note' => '(*.jpg, *.png, *.gif)',
));
```

Comment: I just noticed that in your controller, you just save the filename. You have to save the whole path in your model (i.e. `$model->setImage($path.$model->getId().'.jpg');`)

Comment: Yes but I don't have any problem because of that.

Comment: This is because of you have store your image in Subdirectory of media folder so you have to setvalue() of your image field before display..
like on editAction()

Answer (score 0):

This is because of you have store your image in Subdirectory of media folder so you have to setvalue() of your image field before display..
like in EditAction() add this code here is my field name profile_pic

```
if($model->getProfilePic())
{
  $model->setProfilePic('testimonial/'.$model->getProfilePic());
}
```

OR you can use  helper to preview that image